# How do I customise automatically-generated script?

Tags: unity

When you create a script via the Unity editor, it generates a script with some pre-formatted code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenericClass : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

When I create a script, I am generally guaranteed to use additional code, such as a namespace or a custom editor. Furthermore, I almost *always* delete content from the automatically-generated script. Is there a way to change the automatic code generated by Unity?

Comment: I never even thought about doing this.  Thanks for asking! Now to combine the two answers to have a template *and* then parse it to insert extra information, like namespace...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition you can also

1. Add an editor script in Assets/Editor folder that subscribes to `OnWillCreateAsset` where you can parse the output and modify it. For example script that would automatically insert namespace could look like following:

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

   using UnityEditor;

   public class InsertNS : UnityEditor.AssetModificationProcessor
   {
       public static void OnWillCreateAsset(string path)
       {
           string assetPath = Regex.Replace(path, @".meta$", string.Empty);
           if (!assetPath.EndsWith(".cs")) return;

           var code = File.ReadAllLines(assetPath).ToList();
           if (code.Any(line => line.Contains("namespace"))) return;//already added by IDE

           //insert namespace
           int idx = code.FindIndex(line => line
               .Contains("class " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assetPath)));
           code.Insert(idx, Regex.Replace(
           assetPath.Replace('/','.'), @"^([\w+.]+)\.\w+\.cs$", "namespace $1 {\n"));
           code.Add("}");

           //correct indentation
           for (int i = idx + 1; i < code.Count - 1; i++) code[i] = '\t' + code[i];

           var finalCode = string.Join("\n", code.ToArray());
           File.WriteAllText(assetPath, finalCode);
           AssetDatabase.Refresh();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Insert own control sequences into templates for easy replacing in `OnWillCreateAsset`, e.g.

   ```
   finalCode = finalCode.Replace(@"#date#", DateTime.Now);
   ```
3. Add more templates to the template folder, for example one for Singleton pattern - Unity is not limited to single script template.
4. The visual studio [code snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) are way to customizing creating new scripts (...and even further - new script parts). For example, a code snippet for private `SerializeField` might come in handy. After importing `privateField.snippet`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
     <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
       <Header>
         <Title>
           Serialized private field
         </Title>
         <Author>Myself</Author>
         <Description>Adds private serializable field visible to Unity editor</Description>
         <Shortcut>pf</Shortcut>
       </Header>
       <Snippet>
         <Imports>
           <Import>
             <Namespace>UnityEngine</Namespace>
           </Import>
         </Imports>
         <Declarations>
           <Literal>
             <ID>FieldName</ID>
             <ToolTip>Replace with field name.</ToolTip>
             <Default>myField</Default>
           </Literal>
         </Declarations>
         <Code Language="CSharp">
           <![CDATA[[SerializeField] float _$FieldName$;]]>
         </Code>
       </Snippet>
     </CodeSnippet>
   </CodeSnippets>
   ```

   to *Tools/Code Snippet Manager/My Code Snippets* you can just type "pf" double tab and type the field's name. E.g.:

   ```
   //"pf" tab tab "speed" produces
   [SerializeField] float _speed;
   ```

   Even more convenient would be snippets for often repeated longer sequences,   e.g. readonly property backed by `SerializeField` field.
5. Visual studio also offer very powerful code generation tool, the [T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)(EF is using T4), though I personally find the practical use for Unity projects doubtful - they are overkill, quite complicated and the compilation of project would likely become dependent on Visual Studio.

Comment: This has worked like a charm! I have added relevant namespaces for future users. I also had one more problem, though I think it might be one unique to me; I can not use `Path.GetFileWithoutExtension`. It tells me it is *trying* to access a `MonoBehaviour`, which seems odd. I include the namespace `using Path = System.IO.Path.GetFileWithoutExtension`, and I lose `Path` all together. In the end, I had to fully fledge the line, itself (`.Contains("class " + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assetPath)));`).

Comment: What's the simplest way to ensure files are created with LF and UTF-8 rather than CRLF and UTF-8 with BOM?

Comment: @AaronFranke well... thats rather specific request. I would try asking on stackoverflow.com how to make `string`/`File.Write` output LF-only with BOM. As far as I know '\n' *should* be just LF, you can also try `Environment.Newline` instead but it should be CRLF. There might also an option to use git hooks if everything else fails. BOM should be easy with this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266069/streamwriter-and-utf-8-byte-order-marks).

Answer (score 14):

You can find the script templates for automatically generating code in your Unity installation folder. I find the templates under *"Unity/Editor/Data/Resources/ScriptTemplates"*, while [other sources](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/120957/change-the-default-script-template.html) have found it under *"Unity/Editor/Data/Resources"*.

The generic UnityScript and C# templates are identified as the files *"82-Javascript-NewBehaviourScript.js.txt"* and *"81-C# Script-NewBehaviourScript.cs.txt"*, respectively. You can directly edit these files to change the way in which Unity auto generates script.

You can also include additional templates, which will appear when you select *"Create"* from the *"Project"* window. Templates do not *appear* to require unique numbering, and use the initial string to determine the menu hierarchy, where "__" denotes a submenu. For example, having a file named *"81-C# Script__Editor Script-NewBehaviourScript.cs.txt"* will give you an additional "*C# Script"* menu, with the sub option to create an *"Editor Script"* using this template.

Do ***not*** rename the original templates; these are used more directly, by the engine. For example, renaming *"81-C# Script-NewBehaviourScript.cs.txt"* will prevent you from adding new C# scripts as components, directly through the inspector.

---

Below is my own example, though it demonstrates particular practices that I am most custom to. For example, I prefer to have my custom editor script in the same file as the target class, so I encapsulate it in `#if UNITY_EDITOR .. #endif`, instead of placing it in a generic "do not compile in build" editor folder.

I am not sure if it is even possible to provide the context of a custom namespace; I simply use "NAMESPACE", as this allows me to provide the correct namespace post-creation, using the commonly-inbuilt "find..replace all" function.

---

#### The Template:

```
/* Created by Gnemlock */

using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

namespace NAMESPACE
{
    public class #SCRIPTNAME# : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        /// <summary>This method will be called at the start of each frame where this 
        /// instance of <see cref="NAMESPACE.#SCRIPTNAME#"/> is enabled.</summary>
        void Update ()
        {
            #NOTRIM#
        }
    }
}

namespace NAMESPACE.UTILITY
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(#SCRIPTNAME#))] public class #SCRIPTNAME#Editor : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            DrawDefaultInspector();

            #SCRIPTNAME# s#SCRIPTNAME# = target as #SCRIPTNAME#;
        }
    }
    #endif
}
```

#### The Output:

```
/* Created by Gnemlock */

using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

namespace MyNamespace
{

    public class UpdatedClass : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        /// <summary>This method will be called at the start of each frame where this 
        /// instance of <see cref="MyNamespace.UpdatedClass"/> is enabled.</summary>
        void Update ()
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace.UTILITY
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(UpdatedClass))] public class UpdatedClassEditor : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            DrawDefaultInspector();

            UpdatedClass sUpdatedClass = target as UpdatedClass;
        }
    }
    #endif
}
```