# How to create a directory template in Unity?

Tags: unity, tools, editors

How to create a directory from a template with multiple files in it which are also created from templates?

Right now, I am particularly interested in creating an Assembly directory which uses a user-entered variable `ASSEMBLY_NAME`, take the project name variable from the settings and would create the following simple file hierarchy:

- `${ASSEMBLY_NAME}`/

  - `${PROJECT_NAME}.${ASSEMBLY_NAME}.asmdef`

where the `${PROJECT_NAME}.${ASSEMBLY_NAME}.asmdef` file would contain:

```json
{
  "name": "${PROJECT_NAME}.${ASSEMBLY_NAME}"
}
```

... but I would also be glad to learn any way to create whatever complex templated hierarchies, like creating a class and a companion test script together at once, create a directory with a "readme" file in it, etc.

I know this is somehow possible, because there is a default Unity UI function which does exactly the same, but for test assemblies only, so it adds extra code in the assembly definition file which I don't need.

[image]

I cannot find anything on this topic apart from answers on how to create/edit a *single file templates*, e.g.:

- [How do I customise automatically-generated script?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141188/how-do-i-customise-automatically-generated-script/141189)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461801/unity-add-default-namespace-to-script-template